# react-hot-loader still reload not HMR

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-hmr

I have *webpack.config.js* as shown below, running `webpack-dev-server` using `npm run dev`, whenever changes are detected it still results hard reloading not HMR

[image]

Please guide, what went wrong here, thanks

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'entry.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ]
}
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
    presets: ['stage-0', 'es2015', 'react'],
    plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel']
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **module.hot.accept** in *entry.js* file?:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Navigation from './Navigation';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');
const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
   <Component/>,
   rootEl
  )
};

render(Navigation);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./Navigation', () => {
    render(Navigation)
  })
}
```

[WebPack HMR official docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html)

[Interesting issue](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/508)